# Резервное копирование SQLite3 базы данных с любого хостинга

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Мне очень интересно, как можно сделать бэкап моей базы данных с какого-либо хостинга на мой компьютер. Ведь, при любом сбое, БД просто удаляется. Как это можно сделать, используя SQLite3 и python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример из официального хелпа https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.backup

```
import sqlite3

def progress(status, remaining, total):
    print(f'Copied {total-remaining} of {total} pages...')

con = sqlite3.connect('existing_db.db')
bck = sqlite3.connect('backup.db')
with bck:
    con.backup(bck, pages=1, progress=progress)
bck.close()
con.close()
```

Дальше файл или к себе скачиваете, или в облако, или в любое другое место.

Comment: А как я смогу это сохранить, если случится сбой, ведь и БД и бэкап удалятся. Все вернется к состоянию, когда я заливал это

Comment: У Вас `sqlite` в памяти или на диске? И почему бэкап должен удалиться? Можно файл скриптом в cron копировать в любое место раз в сколько-то минут/часов/дней

Comment: База данных выложена на хостинг, если на хостинге будет перезагрузка, то она скорее всего удаляется, мне надо делать бэкап ее к себе на компьютер.

Comment: Если она не хранится в оперативной памяти, а на диске, то не удалится. Иначе надо сдампить ее на диск, а после уже макросом каким-то или руками загрузить. Очень странный хостинг, если на перезагрузке удаляется все. Обычно под python все-таки какой-то vps берется.